# Can I have links to my deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban

I was banned from asking questions and I only have 4 questions that I can see in my profile. There were a few more that were deleted, and I'd like to get links to those, then undelete and edit them. After reading [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) and its first answer, I saw that it said to create a support question here on meta and ask for links to those deleted questions. So could somebody who is able to give me those links?

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/64683542) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/64543733) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/64229011) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/64120620) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/63957979) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/63848134)

Comment: Those are _all_ your deleted questions, in fact.

Comment: In that list from Martijn: 1 needs an Python expert explain what is wrong with it ( @Martijn ? ); 2 is off-topic on SO; 3 is too broad; 4 is too broad / not a programming problem; 5 if you tried everything, include what you tried. You might have searched for the wrong problem or you have a valid corner case that is not covered in *all* the posts you found on the problem; 6 is too broad but maybe salvageable if you add an attempt (that is working code) so we can go from there.

Comment: @rene: 1. is correctly closed as duplicate; `usr` is a local name in the `run` function because it is being assigned to (`usr = []` further down in the function). The solution is to add a `global usr` statement in the function to tell Python it is a global variable instead, as the top, accepted answer on the duplicate explains. Not much you can do to salvage that one, in future do *search* for the specific error; Googling for `python UnboundLocalError local variable referenced before assignment` should give a lot of good starting points for research.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Should I still un-delete it? Or should I keep it deleted if I can't salvage it?

Comment: @TylerSelden: I don't know. You are going to have to guess as to what future votes on the post will be. Duplicate posts can be valuable as sign posts, but the unbound local variable error is very well covered on Stack Overflow already. You are just as likely to receive more downvotes as upvotes on that if undeleted.

Comment: Check your browser history, @TylerSelden.